# HTTP Cache: no requests

Tags: http, http-caching

I'm having trouble reading the network graph in DevTools. My objective is to cache all request, both on intermediate proxies and in the browser, resulting in zero requests on a primed cache. I even pre-fetch some resources before inserting them in the DOM, so an empty cache should also not make all requests.

I have set the `cache-control` directive to **public, max-age: 3600** during development.

[image]
*Firefox*

[image]
*Chromium*

An example is the last two image requests. Before I insert them in the DOM, I do a pre-fetch request (the two xhr before the last two images), which with `cache-control` set, should mean don't do a request, just load from cache. What I see is that there is two new request, but with no data transferred from the server, which takes 12-14ms. That only gets me halfway there. I don't want any requests at all!

This is just an example, the idea is do this with hundreds of requests via a manager that *predicts* which images (and SVGs) to load.

Each request also has an `ETag` which comes by default from the HTTP server I use. I have to support IE11, so service workers are out of the picture.

Comment: It will have to *load the resource* from somewhere. It would be madness for the browser to have alternative code paths internally for whether something is in cache or not. It's going to make an attempt to *load the resource*, and the resource loader is going to return it *from disk cache* without making a network request. That loading attempt is what's showing up there, the *(from disk cache)* means no network request was made.

Comment: Thanks. I suspected that but I wasn't sure how to read the DevTools (the first sentence in my post). Do you mind creating an answer I can accept - preferably with a linkable resource to back your claim?